# Node Callback array undefined (empty value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I im using node js to pass data from watcher every few seconds to function streamplay that stores id.ts filenames in array this works fine as it stores but when i callback from another function in my program i get undefined value from this array....and i can't figure out how it needs to be written:

```
var stream_play = [];

watch('/tmp/1_.m3u8', function(event, name) {
    /* DEFINE - variables */
    var ts    = [];
    ts.push(1);

    streamplay(id, ts[ts.length-1]);
});

function streamplay(id, ts, callback) {
   /* CHECH - ts */
   if (ts !== 0) {
      console.log('adding id..'+id+'...with ts...'+ts)
      stream_play[id] = ts;
   } else {
      return callback(stream_play[id]);
   }
}
```

And calling from main function in node like this:

```
 streamplay(stream, 0, function(response) {
       console.log('streaming ts file...'+response+'...to client...')                   
       res.write(fs.readFileSync('/tmp/'+response));
  })
```

I get this:

```
streaming ts file...undefined...to client...
```

Comment: Because `stream_play` array is empty

Answer (score 3):

Your function call, `streamplay(stream, 0, function(response) {` will end up falling through to your else condition in `streamplay`. This line is       `return callback(stream_play[id]);` and the `stream_play` array is initialized, but empty. Accessing a non-existent element in a JavaScript array returns `undefined`.

Comment: Yes i know that is empty but how to make array globally to make it to return value...i put variable outside function to make it globally but array is still empty

Comment: One option would be to define `stream_play` like this: `var stream_play = [0];`

Comment: I added var stream_play = [0]; globally but it is sam undefined

Comment: No one have idea what it needs to done? Maybe using buffers? I read on node that buffer is global and is accessed throught whole node js application...i im using using ts fs.readfilesync...so maybe this can be done globally?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and another problem...the first example using callback works now like charm. The problem was that i have master process and worker process and i read on node js site that master and worker process can't share between variables values...so the new question is how to share master and worker process variables so that i can access from all worker process variables values from master?

I im doing clustering with this because of my huge server load and cpu clustering is must to go.